# Difference between cordova and android studio

Tags: android, cordova

What do you advice me to learn if I have a senior project in the university.
Cordova or android studio and as you know that Cordova can make for you an android studio and IOS bearing in mind that I want to be a App developer but I thought that if I learn first Cordova to make my project then I will learn the android studio if I want to be more Professional and if I want to modify more the App that were created by the Cordova.
Thanks for your help and please give me an expert adivce my choice will depend on you.

Comment: you should ask difference between HTML5 and JAVA and not over IDE. Native development (JAVA is this case) is always be better and have full advantage of the SDK.

Comment: I didn't say the difference between HTML5 and JAVA because I mean that Cardova can make for you app with a copy for different platforms so it is more easy then writing first an app for android then a second time for IOS you got my point?

Comment: Most HTML5 frameworks (like Cordova) are multi platform... true, easy to have an iOS version later. BUT: You need a Mac with OSX and XCode anyway to develop in Cordova iOS, you'll need to change the UI in both platforms (Apple will not accept an app with Android look and feel UI/UX and you will get bad reviews in Android with iOS look) and if you don't have much knowledge in Js it won't be an easy task.

Comment: So what you advice me to do? Learn android studio or learn Cordova then when I finish my project and get graduated I return to learn android to be more professional within applications developing???

Comment: I advise you to learn how to do your own research and make up your own mind. A college graduate should be able to do that. Don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

These choices are completely different. Android Studio is a RAD tool used for to development App using Java or Kotlin as language. And Cordova is a platform that can build the web applications(html5, js, css) as a native App. But the app is run on another platfom called as 'webview' on OS'.

*Disadvantages of using Cordova:*

*Operational:* Because of webview, the app faces major challanges. One of these is that, when you send the app to the background if you use a socket communication in the app the connection will be lost. (If there is a developed tool to overcome issues regarding the app the tool may be used. Otherwise, the tool has to be developed by the app developer by using Java or Kotlin. So, at every aspect native coding [by using Java or Kotlin] is a must)

*Visual:* Because of Webview, the app that is built by Cordova, cannot use the GPU for graphics and animates. That is a big disadvantage when using the app.

Because of this basic problem I would choose the Android Studio with Java or Kotlin.

Good luck...

Comment: problems like what? you mean problems found in these softwares? So what you advice me to do? Learn android studio or learn Cordova then when I finish my project and get graduated I return to learn android to be more professional within applications developing???

Comment: Problems that appearances when you developing by yourself. I don't know your project but the projects have a lot of pieces. I mean, if this is your first project, get ready and be patient. Just philosophy :)